# Hashem created this world l'heitiv labriyos

Tags: creation

so Hashem only does good, only wants to do good,...
so why arent we born in gan eiden?
answer: we shudnt feel stupid with getting things for granted... 
people dont feel good that way, people like to get things they deserve, so hashem was nice, he put us onto this world and gives us tonz of schar for evth we do, so when we come up there we shud feel great abt ourselves!

so here goes:
whyyyyy are we like that? cuz thats the taiva.
so whyyy is that the nature?!
why did hashem make that we shud feel good like that and not good the other way...
the question is quite primitive, the initial base, the essence of us. and the world. and the purpose.

Comment: Hi Schar. How do you know all the things in your first paragraph? Please [edit] to clarify as your whole question seems based on that particular perspective.

Comment: This is a statement and not a question. Mi Yodeya is a question and answer format and not a discussion forum. You should also write in grammatical English so that it can be understood.

Comment: He wants to give the ultimate good which is of Himself. just like He IS good, i.e. the owner of good, so too the only way to give this over to some degree is if the recipient is also the owner of this good. thus we need to earn it. same thing as you say in different words